# Sending notifications to multiple users in FCM with different data using python

Tags: python

I am trying to send notifications to multiple users using FCM. I am aware that I can send bulk notifications by using `"registration_ids": ["fcm_token1", "fcm_token2"]` in my python code. But the thing is, I need to send different data to each `fcm_token` depending on their status. Calling the url to send notifications multiple time will not be a good thing to do, because it is going to block the server. And spawning threads might also not be a good idea. Is there anyway possible to send notifications in bulk with different data.

Edit:

Im not using `pyfcm`, I'm using `requests` to perform the POST request at `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send` using my api token.